# Input some numbers and at the end print the sum, average, standard deviations

Tags: python

Input some numbers and at the end print the sum, average, Standard Deviation,
largest and smallest from them all. The program should keep inputting numbers until the
user types “END”. Any number which is not numeric should not be considered, and instead
of your program terminating by giving an error, your program should display appropriate
messages, and allow re-entry of the number. We should be able to enter integers as well as
float numbers. ( If time permits, extend the project to display the list of numbers in sorted
order along with the frequency of occurrence. In this display, a number should be displayed
only once )

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems like you're asking for someone to write the entire program for you. Try to divide the problem it into small parts, work on each of them, and then if you run into specific problems ask a question

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    # Getting input using input function. Then changing type to integer. 
    num1 = float(input())
    num2 = float(input())

    # Sum
    sum = num1 + num2 # Using mathematical operations to compute value. 
    print("Sum: " + sum) # Printing to console. 

    # Average
    average = (num1 + num2)/2
    print("Average: " + average)
```

This is how you would go about doing the sum and average. You can now expand on from this to get the program you want. It is a matter of knowing how to do the mathematical operations in Python, and implementing them. You can use if-statements for the specific cases you want to check or handle.

Note : In the future please refrain from simply asking for the entire solution to a problem. Please attempt it and only once you run into problems and have tried to solve it, then only should you ask for help.